# Error running (foo)tex on Linux: "undefined symbol: kpathsea_cnf_line_env_progname"

Tags: symbols, linux, undefined, kpathsea

G'day,

I have just installed tex on a fresh install of Fedora 32 via the command:

```
dnf install texlive
```

I prefer to manage my tex installation via dnf, and have had success with this command on previous Fedora installs.  The following package appears to be installed:

```
texlive-9:2020-29.fc32.noarch
```

However when I try running lualatex, pdflatex, latex etc I get the following error:

```
lualatex: symbol lookup error: lualatex: undefined symbol: kpathsea_cnf_line_env_progname
```

I've googled the missing symbol but come up blank.  Can anyone offer some help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but fixed by running:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install texlive-lib # thought I might have to do this one, but it worked without it
```

after finding these bug pages:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1899634

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1905248